# Order of accuracy of linearised vs non-linear system

Tags: numerical-analysis, nonlinear-equations, discretization, accuracy

Does the order of accuracy of a combination of schemes applied to solve a system of non-linear equations, match those of the same schemes applied to the linearised version of the system?

In other words, does linearisation alter the order of accuracy of a scheme?

Comment: Are you solving algebraic or differential equations? What methods are you using?

Comment: differential equations (isothermal euler equations close with p=f(rho) for a baratropic flow), solved using FVM and central differencing, periodic bc's.